# Getting ID from database and into the URI

Tags: database, codeigniter

I would like to get the ID of a value from a database and use it to delete an item.
Heres my code:

This code currently gets a set of records from a database, where each record has links. How can I do this?

```
<h2>List of all polls in this site:</h2>
<?php echo '<table>';?>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Text</th>    

    <th colspan="2">Action</th>        
  </tr>
<?php 
foreach($polls as $polls_item){
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>". $polls_item['title'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". $polls_item['text'] ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". anchor('user/vote/'.$polls_item->id,'Vote') ."</td>";
    echo "<td>". anchor('admin/del/'.$polls_item->id,'Delete') ."</td>";        
  echo "</tr>"; 
}
?>

<?php echo anchor('admin/del/1','Delete'); ?>

</table>
```

Comment: Tell me what you got when you hover on the delete link..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume that you have an admin controller, and you loaded admin_model at the beginning which is where you get all your polls

```
class Admin
....
function del($id = null)
{
  $this->admin_model->delete($id);
}
```

Then in your admin_model where polls is the table name of your database

```
class Admin_model
....
function delete($id)
{
 $this->db->delete('polls', array('id' => $id)); 
}
```

I hope this is clear enough.

Comment: Thanks i have that in my admin and model class, Its just that when i run it, id is undefined. I am not sure how to get the id using this?

Comment: did you mean your $polls_item->id gives undefined or it's undefined in the del($id) function?

Comment: @NiraliPatel The line `$polls_item->id` returns the id.. or else you can use `$polls_item['id']`

Comment: the id in $polls_item->id gives undefined.

Comment: you should use $polls_item['id'] as Bhuvan rikka suggested

Comment: you are using trying to access the ID as though it is an object and it appears as though you are using an array to store your values. as the others ave pointed out changing the $polls_item->id to $polls_item['id'] should correct this issue, assuming that the ID column in your DB is `id`.

Comment: You can use print_r($polls_item); to know the data in the object.

Comment: <?php echo anchor('admin/del/1','Delete'); ?>
can someone please explain what this line of code is doing and what the 1 stands for. Sorry i am new to all this code ignitor. Thankyou

Comment: I seem to be getting an error which says "Unable to load the requested class: polls" whats going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You have a `function del` in your "admin" controller:

```
function del($item_to_delete) 
 {
   $this->your_model->delete_item($item_to_delete);
 }
```

In your Model:

```
function delete_item($id)
 {
   $this->db->delete('mytable', array('id' => $id)); 
   // some successful message to return
 }
```

Please, take a look at the Codeigniter [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html#delete)

Comment: Hey thanks.. I have that bit of coding just not sure how to connect it to the delete links for each item..